# sOpen Menu popup programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, windows-mobile

I am developing a Windows Mobile 6.5.3 application. My question is how can I open the Menu popup programmatically.

What I did is I simulate the touch event. by using

[DllImport("coredll")]
        private static extern void mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

but here the problem is I need to specify the location of menu button and also it is showing some glance of mouse pointer, which I don't like...

Is there any message which I can send and the popup for the menu will open?

As requested I am adding some more information. I want to open the popup which opens after pressing the menu button programmatically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Get the context menu from the control then use the `Show()` method of the context menu.

EDIT: answer modified and code changed

This is what I've done to have it work for me.

`ContextMenu ctxMenu = BTN_TheButtonControlThatYouPressed.ContextMenu;
ctxMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.MousePoint;
ctxMenu.IsOpen = true;`

Now, because your context menu has been assigned to your form instead of your button you simply swap out the "BTN_TheButtonControl..." for a simple "this" which should "target" the form.

SO - add the following code to the button's click event and you should be okay.

`ContextMenu ctxMenu = this.ContextMenu;
ctxMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.MousePoint;
ctxMenu.IsOpen = true;`

** not sure what's going on with the carriage returns... can't get 'em to go for just the second block of code...

Comment: The Menu in form is not derived from Control. How do you get the context menu from Menu?

Comment: I've edited my answer with some code for you - give 'er a try!

Comment: Can you add some more details? The question is not that clear.What type is your control that has a conext menu that you will show by code?

Comment: No that code will not work. As the context menu associated with menu bar is different than context menu of form itself.

Comment: Okay then just get the context menu from the toolbar? - is that not possible?

ctxMenu = YourToolBarControl.ContextMenu;

Comment: That is the problem there is no ContextMenu exposed as public for either the Toolbar or Menu or Menuitem. I think there may be some message which I can send and it opens the popup.